# ConjugacyClassesSubgroups ordering in GAP for SmallGroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, gap, computer-algebra-systems

Does GAP always arrange the conjugacy classes of subgroups by the subgroup order when `ConjugacyClassesSubgroups` is executed on a group generated by `SmallGroup`? If not, how can I efficiently get subgroups of a small group by decreasing order (or, equivalently, by increasing index)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The declaration of `ConjugacyClassesSubgroups` does not guarantee that the list is always ordered, and I can imagine situations (such as special methods for subgroups of a direct product) in which it could produce a list that is not sorted.

The easiest way to get a sorted list is probably

```
l:=ShallowCopy(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(group));
SortBy(l,x->Size(Representative(x)));
```

(replace `Size` by `-Size` to get decreasing order).

The cost (both time and memory) for this is probably neglegible.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a reason to use ```Size``` instead of ```Order``` or they compute the order in the same manner?